# Letting users to type the position C#

Tags: c#

We are learning how the list works, also we made our own list not the finished one. So we have couple methods and they're working now I want to make a CMD Menu. And I have the following problem:

```
else if (selectedMenuItem == "2. Press here to insert any text on any position.")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type any text which you want to Insert: ");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Type the position where you want to paste the text: ");
                    int position = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    for (int i = 0; i < zahlen2.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(zahlen2.Insert(position,input);
                    }
                }
```

Zahlen 2:

```
List zahlen2 = new List();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please type five numbers or texts");
                zahlen2.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine($" This is your input , this is what you typed in.{zahlen2}");
```

This is the part of the menu now I went  thorugh the list with loop but the position is underlined with red color . So I wanted to ask for your help how can 
I let users to type the position.

Thanks

Comment: what is zahlen2? it is missing in your code

Comment: zahlen2 is the list with loop from 1 to 5 also u can type the numbers in or texts

Comment: can you add that to you piece of code? When i put this in my editor "postion" is not underlined with red color.

Comment: @Daniel I edited my post now.

Comment: but there is another problem now the input is underlined with red color, should I make 1 more list or ?

Comment: sure. because now you have a List and the insert method on lists is adding an item in the list at the given index. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes the poistion isn't anymore underlined but now the input is it says cannot convert int to string, and I wanted to ask you should I make 1 more list only for texts or ?

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change the declaration from your List like:

```
var zahlen2 = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type five numbers or texts");
    zahlen2.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

Now you have a list of integers that you can iterate.

in the for loop you need to change your lines like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < zahlen2.Count; i++)
{
    // this inserts each zahl into the given input string at position
    input = input.Insert(position, zahlen2[i].ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Looks like this now:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.